# How do I call ACPI control methods from C++ or C# on Windows?

Tags: acpi

I'm getting tired of waiting for HP to fix the switchable graphics driver for my laptop, but I think I can switch GPUs myself by calling ACPI methods. The switching works using vga_switcheroo in Linux, which is open source, so I know what methods I need to call, but not how to call them.

The two methods I need to call are in the SSDT namespace, if that matters, and I also need to pass integer arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some links on similar problems ([For example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/e51049a6-2b86-48be-94a8-36032de88c1e)) say that this is possible only from kernel-mode driver under Windows. So to accomplish this I can think only of the following options:

1. Writing entire videodriver by yourself - I doubt you will go this
   way...
2. Finding documentation on or reverse-engineering existing videodriver
   for your GPU and issuing necessary commands via IOCTLs using
   function `DeviceIoControl` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Also not very reliable -
   existing driver might not contain necessary functions/IOCTLs - but I
   think it will be much easier than the first option.