# Calling methods from DSDT in Windows (ACPI)

Tags: c++, c, windows, acpi, dsdt

I have recently discovered how wonderful modifying the DSDT table in Windows is. I already remapped some Fn keys to do some other things, but those things were located in the actual DSDT (like turn LEDs off, turn fan on/off).

Now, I would like to step up the game and control the things from the OS. Like, define some custom methods in the DSDT, and then using software from Windows, call those things. That would open the door to an entire new level of posibilities.

So, what are the steps to do to acomplish this under Windows, using C++ for example? And, is there an app that can call generic methods from the DSDT already? Because that would be so awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781625/how-do-i-call-acpi-control-methods-from-c-or-c-sharp-on-windows

Comment: Okay, do you know where I can find some example code? Or is there none?

Comment: There probably isn't any example code. You're going to have to write a driver from scratch. Which can probably do what you want directly without having to invoke a custom ACPI method.

Comment: Maybe, IDK. Thanks, will have a look at that. I am surprised though that no one wrote a generic one for Windows yet. And that there is no source code. Not to speak about Linux, but even OS X has an ACPI Debug driver (kernel extension more precisely) which can work with the DSDT...

Comment: The driver you'd need to write isn't a whole video driver, it would just be a simple driver to invoke the ACPI methods you want. You can find a lot of simple example drivers that expose a "device", provide an IOCTL, and then use a Win32 program to invoke the IOCTL. Or maybe you could find a generic ACPI-method-caller driver, similar to what you suggest.

Comment: Yeah, I think I solved it, I used TVicPort. From C# (naturally works from C++ as well). It is free, works on Windows 7 fine as I see. It allows reading from/writing to the embeddded controller, basically exactely what I needed. I am turning on/off the LEDs on my laptop like crazy right now =)) Nice research tho.